# View which http pages are being accessed (realtime) through SSH?

Tags: linux, apache, ssh

Is there a command where I can view which website pages on my server are currently being accessed in realtime through SSH?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, try `tail -f /your/server/log/file.log`.

Comment: Your answer is also valid, so catch +1 from me too sir.

Comment: change the ``-f`` to ``-F`` and it even works in a long-running screen-session with logrotate enabled (``-F`` will make tail re-open the file if it's renamed)

Answer (score 1):

Sure. If your apache configuration has logging enabled, each page view will be written to the access_log. You can use `tail -f access_log` to follow the file.